# Enable X-Frame-Options and set to DENY/SAMEORIGIN in jetty-9.1.0-M0

Tags: java, web-applications, jetty, web.xml, jetty-9

I want to set **X-Frame-Options** HeaderFilter in my Java Webapplication backed by Jetty Server(version 9.1.0-M0). I have checked jetty documentation but i din't find relevant options.

While checking Jetty-9.4.x version documentation, I found that there is HeaderFiler Class which provide support for setting the Header's Value.([See Jetty-9.4.x HeaderFilter](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/header-filter.html))

Any idea how to set Headers in Jetty-9.1.x version server configurations?

PS: I am using web-app 2.5 compliant web.xml.